# Concordance and Discordance role in modelling

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling

I am new to statistics and was asked to develop a statistical model, which I had started, they ask me to carry out concordance and discordance now, however I don't know anything about these terms except that the concordance is the probability that a pair of individuals will both have a certain characteristic, given that one of the pair has the characteristic and the opposite for discordance.
Still I don't know why I have to find them and what would be the appropriate value of both for a decent model.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What sort of model did you develop?

Comment: I am developing a logistic model.

Answer (score 3):

In [this paper](http://www.nesug.org/proceedings/nesug08/sa/sa09.pdf) I cover concordance and discordance. The paper is about `PROC LOGISTIC` in `SAS` but the section on concordance is more general. Briefly: Look at all possible pairs of observations. A pair is concordant if the observation with the higher observed value also has the higher predicted value.

Comment: I read your paper, but I am not able to understand what is the meaning of getting concordance and discordance as 25.0 and how to know by this whether the model is good or not